# Help with change of variables for evaluating $\iint_S (x^2-y^2)e^{(x+y)^2} \,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable, bounds-of-integration

I have $$\iint_S (x^2-y^2)e^{(x+y)^2}\,dx\,dy $$ with restrictions $x+y\leq3$, $ xy\geq2$ and $y\leq x$

I think that with the variable changes $$u=x+y$$  and  $$v=x-y$$

whose Jacobian is $2$
then I have the integral:
$$\frac{1}{2}\iint_S u v e^{(u)^2} $$ My problem is when taking the limits of $u$ and $v$, someone can help me, i think the limits are

$$0\leq v \leq1 $$  and   $$\sqrt{8+v^2}\leq u \leq 3 $$

Comment: Note $x=(u+v)/2$ and $y=(u-v)/2$ so the condition $xy\ge 3$ becomes $(u^2-v^2)/4 \ge 3$.

Comment: The new limits look correct to me!